# How can I compare two arrays if inside the arrays some strings are similar?

Tags: php, arrays

I simply want to compare two strings

```
$result = array_diff($original, $new);
```

var_dump $original:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "8344"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "7076"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "6220940"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "6220940"
}
```

var_dump $new:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "8344"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "7076"
  [2]=>
  string(14) "6220940mistake"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "6220940"
}
```

var_dump $result:

```
array(0) {
}
```

But what I actually expect would be var_dump $result:

```
array(1) {
  [2]=>
  string(7) "6220940"
}
```

I found out that this is happening because I have two strings that are similar. So if every string is unique, there is no problem. But I do sometimes have also similar strings inside my array. Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: So, I expect that the indexes also need to match? You'll have to use a `foreach` to test it index by index.

Comment: Thank you Andrius, but I still do not understand. `[2]=>
  string(7) "6220940"` is different to `[3]=>
  string(7) "6220940"`. The string is the same but the keys are different.

Comment: I'm just asking if what you're trying to accomplish is to check if the values in the same indexes of different arrays are matching. Can't you go through the array indexes and check the values of both and insert to the new array what values do not match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = array("8344", "7076", "6220940", "6220940");
$b = array("8344", "7076", "6220940mistake", "6220940");

var_export(array_diff_assoc($a,$b));
```

prints

```
array (
  2 => '6220940',
)
```

see [array_diff_assoc](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php)

Comment: Thank you `array_diff_assoc` was what I needed

Answer (score 1):

You have empty result because all of the elements in `$orginal` array are present in array you are comparing against (`$new`) - value "6220940" is present at index 3.

You should use `array_diff_assoc` instead of `array_diff` so you will be comparing array elements with their index assignment.

Comment: great! This was solving the problem :)